# What do the floating droplets during the Black Alert in Discovery mean?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In Star Trek Discovery S01:E03 *[Context is For Kings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode))* we see Burnham's introduction to the Discovery.

In particular we hear a Black Alert and see floating droplets.

[image]

My question is: **What do the floating droplets during the Black Alert in Discovery mean?**

Comment: A visual cue for the hearing impaired?

Comment: I assumed they were meant to be an anomaly resulting from the inefficient use of the computer to perform the spore jump. They seemed to disappear after the crew switched to Ripper as navigator (and then still gone later when Stamets took over).

Comment: @delinear Are you willing to turn your comment into an answer? That seems plausible.

Comment: @delinear - not trying to steal your answer, if you want the credit, you can have it. but after 1 year+, I figure you don't care

Comment: @LevenTrek absolutely no problem! I was hoping at some point I'd have chance to revisit the theory and maybe flesh it out with some examples, but I'm struggling to make time and it's good that there is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The water droplets only appear when the Discovery uses Stamets' computer program as a navigator.

Once Ripper becomes the navigator, the droplets cease. And they still don't happen after Stamets takes over.

It must be a bug or flaw in Stamets' program.